# Append Dataframes together in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, append

I feel like this should be simple but I'm still a bit new to Python and am struggling to figure out what I should do. I'm scraping historical stock data and would like to put them into one excel spreadsheet. It currently only writes out the last stock data.

I know it is essentially writing over the dataframe each time it goes through the loop but I'm not sure how to fix it to append dataframes, or write to the end of the excel sheet each time it gets to that spot. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time

symbols = ['WYNN', 'FL', 'TTWO']
myColumnHeaders = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']

for c in range(len(symbols)):
    url = 'https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/'+symbols[c]+'/historical'
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    historicaldata = soup.find('div', {'id': 'quotes_content_left_pnlAJAX'})
    data_rows = historicaldata.findAll('tr')[2:]
    stock_data = [[td.getText().strip() for td in data_rows[a].findAll('td')]
                 for a in range(len(data_rows))]
    df = pd.DataFrame(stock_data, columns=myColumnHeaders)
    df.set_index('Date')

    df['Volume'].str.replace(',','').astype(int)
    for i in range(5):
        if i == 0:
            df[myColumnHeaders[i]] = pd.to_datetime(df[myColumnHeaders[i]], 'coerce')
        else:
            df[myColumnHeaders[i]] = pd.to_numeric(df[myColumnHeaders[i]], errors='coerce')

df.to_excel('stock data.xlsx',index=False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Do not use `pd.DataFrame.append` in a loop

This is inefficient as it involves copying data repeatedly. A much better idea is to create a list of dataframes and then concatenate them at the end in a final step outside your loop. Here's some pseudo-code:

```
symbols = ['WYNN', 'FL', 'TTWO']
cols = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']

dfs = []  # empty list which will hold your dataframes

for c in range(len(symbols)):
    # some code

    df = pd.DataFrame(stock_data, columns=cols)
    df = df.set_index('Date')

    df['Volume'] = df['Volume'].str.replace(',', '').astype(int)

    df[cols[0]] = pd.to_datetime(df[cols[0]], errors='coerce')
    df[cols[1:5]] = df[cols[1:5]].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')

    dfs.append(df)  # append dataframe to list

res = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)  # concatenate list of dataframes
res.to_excel('stock data.xlsx', index=False)
```

Note you are performing many operations, e.g. `set_index`, as if they are by default *in place*. That's not the case. You should assign back to a variable, e.g. `df = df.set_index('Date')`.

Comment: This is really..really helpful and to be noted. :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've been pretty busy but I should be able to get back to this tonight and mark an answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your code in order to get all the data in a single DataFrame.

```
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time

symbols = ['WYNN', 'FL', 'TTWO']
myColumnHeaders = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']

dfs = []

for c in range(len(symbols)):
    url = 'https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/'+symbols[c]+'/historical'
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    historicaldata = soup.find('div', {'id': 'quotes_content_left_pnlAJAX'})
    data_rows = historicaldata.findAll('tr')[2:]
    stock_data = [[td.getText().strip() for td in data_rows[a].findAll('td')]
                 for a in range(len(data_rows))]
    df = pd.DataFrame(stock_data, columns=myColumnHeaders)
    df.set_index('Date')
    df['Volume'].str.replace(',','').astype(int)
    for i in range(5):
        if i == 0:
            df[myColumnHeaders[i]] = pd.to_datetime(df[myColumnHeaders[i]], 'coerce')
        else:
            df[myColumnHeaders[i]] = pd.to_numeric(df[myColumnHeaders[i]], errors='coerce')
    df.index = [symbols[c]]*len(df)
    dfs.append(df)

df = dfs[0].append(dfs[1]).append(dfs[2]).reset_index()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='data', index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I used both yours and the answer I voted for combined as they were both great.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm a newbie to pandas as well.
>   I think this is a good question and I am sure there is a simple way to do it, but this is what I came up with...

```
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time

symbols = ['WYNN', 'FL', 'TTWO']

stocklist = []
for c in range(len(symbols)):
    url = 'https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/'+symbols[c]+'/historical'
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    historicaldata = soup.find('div', {'id': 'quotes_content_left_pnlAJAX'})
    data_rows = historicaldata.findAll('tr')[2:]
    stock_data = [[td.getText().strip() for td in data_rows[a].findAll('td')]for a in range(len(data_rows))]
    stocklist.append(stock_data)

df0 = pd.DataFrame(stocklist[0], columns = ['Date', 'Open '+symbols[0], 'High '+symbols[0], 'Low '+symbols[0], 'Close '+symbols[0], 'Volume '+symbols[0]])
df0.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(stocklist[1], columns = ['Date', 'Open '+symbols[1], 'High '+symbols[1], 'Low '+symbols[1], 'Close '+symbols[1], 'Volume '+symbols[1]])
df1.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(stocklist[2], columns = ['Date', 'Open '+symbols[2], 'High '+symbols[2], 'Low '+symbols[2], 'Close '+symbols[2], 'Volume '+symbols[2]])
df2.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df3 = df0.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_index=True)
df = df3.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)

VW = df['Volume WYNN'].str.replace(',','').astype(int)
FL = df['Volume FL'].str.replace(',','').astype(int)
TTWO = df['Volume TTWO'].str.replace(',','').astype(int)
df['Volume WYNN'] = VW
df['Volume FL'] = FL
df['Volume TTWO'] = TTWO 

df.to_excel('stock data.xlsx',index=False)
```